# Porting project from flashpunk to which platform?

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, game-engine

The project Flashpunk is seeming to be closed. And the official site is also removed. I want to move my code to another engine **with no or minimal code change**.

What is the successor of it? if no, which one should be my target?

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it." [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, what is the advantage of moving to another engine if it's going to do the same thing? If you have a stable release of FlashPunk and are capable / familiar with it, then continue using it. The only disadvantage I can see is that if their site is no longer in operation, you won't be able to take advantage of the community. With that said, there are still many other resources online full of people who are comfortable with FlashPunk.

Secondly, you're not going to be able to move to another engine with no or minimal change. Each engine may aim to serve the same purpose (simple game development) but the implementation is very different. You won't be able to simply import another entire engine and change a few `extends` statements to the new classes, that just won't happen.

Finally, FlashPunk is old technology. New engines like [Starling](http://gamua.com/starling/) are around now, which take advantage of the newest APIs like `Stage3D` to greatly improve rendering performance. You should consider moving to a newer engine.

Comment: I have picked up one of my projects which is discontinued the development. Anyway, thanks for your information but I would rather listen to more voice from Flashpunk developers.

Answer (score 0):

FlashPunk 2 is going to come out sometime this year, but until then, we just have to wait for the site to come back up. I wanted to get into FlashPunk, but it's down. It's going to be pretty much the same as before (I think) with a plethora of new features, so why not wait for that?

Comment: where can i keep track on FP2's progress? I am even wondering will it be released. More importantly I can hardly found documentations and solutions through the internet after flashpunk.net was down.

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to check out the work of KickBack Games: http://www.kickbackgames.com.

They have a version of FlashPunk that uses Stage3D so is much faster, and is still being maintained.